# parole player gives gstreamer error when trying to play a video encoded with libx264

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-player, gstreamer, h264

i have a bunch of png files with which i create a video using ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i frame%d.png -c:v libx264 a.mpg
```

VLC can play this video, but when i try to open it with Parole Media Player, i get the error:

> GStreamer backend error No valid frames found before end of stream

However if i simply create the video like this:

```
ffmpeg -i frame%d.png a.mpg
```

Parole can then open it.

Would somebody know where the problem could come from? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Thank you so much - putting .mp4 solved it! I thought it was some problems with libraries of gstreamer or something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For H.264 video use a more common output container format such as `.mp4`, `.mkv`, `.ts`, etc. Also, add `-pix_fmt yuv420p` if you want dumb players (WMP, QuickTime) to be able to decode it properly.